# TestNG doesn't re-run all failed methods after ElementClickInterceptedException

Tags: java, selenium, selenide, retry-logic

I have an automation framework TestNG + Selenide which runs jobs on Jenkins and provides Allure reports.
I've added a test class with some simple tests. One test occasionally fails when trying to click an element, but rerunning fixes the problem, so naturally I wanted to introduce retries for this test.

Here comes the problem - failed tests are not retried. I've tried IRetryAnalyzer/RetryAnalyzerCount added via annotation transformer or adding retryAnalyzer to @Test annotation, but no success.

My current configuration:

```
public class RetryAnalyzer extends RetryAnalyzerCount {

    private static final int MAX_RETRY_ATTEMPTS = 3;

    public RetryAnalyzer() {
        setCount(MAX_RETRY_ATTEMPTS);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retryMethod(ITestResult iTestResult) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
public class AnnotationTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AnnotationTransformer.class);

    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
        annotation.setRetryAnalyzer(RetryAnalyzer.class);
        logger.debug("SET RETRY ANALYZER FOR TEST {}", testMethod.getName());
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="E2 widget tests" thread-count="6" parallel="classes" data-provider-thread-count="3">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="framework.AnnotationTransformer"/>
    </listeners>
    <test name="E2 widgets - chrome">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
        <parameter name="width" value="1366"/>
        <parameter name="height" value="786"/>
        <packages>
            <package name="tests.other.e2widgets" />
        </packages>
    </test>

</suite>
```

My test + dataprovider it's using

```
    @DataProvider(name = "countries-with-odds-widget-enabled", parallel = true)
    public Object[][] countriesWithOddsWidgetEnabled() {
        List<String> oddsWidgetCountries = sevWidgetSteps.getOddsWidgetCountries(configUrl);
        List<Object[]> parameters = oddsWidgetCountries.stream().map(country -> new Object[]{country}).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return parameters.toArray(new Object[1][parameters.size()]);
    }

    @Test(description = "Check odds widget for all countries",
            dataProvider = "countries-with-odds-widget-enabled"
    )
    public void checkOddsWidgetsForEnabledCountries(String country) {
        ...some code...

        // here test fails because of ElementClickInterceptedException
        $(By.id("3__match-calendar-link")).click();

        proxy.stop();
        softly.assertAll();
    }
```

Error I see in the allure report:

```
Invalid element state [[id*='match-calendar-link'][3]]: element click intercepted: Element <a id="3__match-calendar-link" class="zh Eh">...</a> is not clickable at point (690, 296). Other element would receive the click: <div class="Mg"></div>
Screenshot: file:/Users/jenkins/workspace/UI-SANDBOX/build/reports/tests/1653409276041.25.png
Page source: file:/Users/jenkins/workspace/UI-SANDBOX/build/reports/tests/1653409276041.25.html
Timeout: 10 s.
Caused by: ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <a id="3__match-calendar-link" class="zh Eh">...</a> is not clickable at point (690, 296). Other element would receive the click: <div class="Mg"></div>
```

I expect the test to be retried if that click method fails, but in allure report I can see no retries, though if method doesn't fail at this point but later due to assertion - it will be retried. Hope somebody can help me to figure this out, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to add maven surefire plugin to your pom.xml if you don't have it

```xml
<dependencies>
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```